# UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp437 after zxing update

Tags: android, zxing

I just tried to update my project from zxing core 2.3.0 to 3.0.0 and experience this charset problem. Not sure yet if this is a bug or if I have to provide the charsets now in some way - can anyone shed a light on it? Should I open a issue on github for this or can I provide the charsets in any way?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.google.zxing.pdf417.encoder.PDF417.<init>(PDF417.java:531)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.google.zxing.pdf417.encoder.PDF417.<init>(PDF417.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.google.zxing.pdf417.PDF417Writer.encode(PDF417Writer.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter.encode(MultiFormatWriter.java:94)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter.encode(MultiFormatWriter.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at org.ligi.passandroid.helper.BarcodeHelper.getBitMatrix(BarcodeHelper.java:51)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at org.ligi.passandroid.helper.BarcodeHelper.generateBarCodeBitmap(BarcodeHelper.java:23)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at org.ligi.passandroid.model.Passbook.getBarcodeBitmap(Passbook.java:322)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at org.ligi.passandroid.ui.TicketViewActivity.onCreate(TicketViewActivity.java:86)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287): Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: Cp437
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:303)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    at com.google.zxing.pdf417.encoder.PDF417HighLevelEncoder.<clinit>(PDF417HighLevelEncoder.java:128)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4287):    ... 23 more
```

Comment: a small workaround would be setting the EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET to "ISO-8859-1". CP437 is the default charset for PDF417 as defined by the specification. It seems that CP437 isn't available on android or has another name.

Comment: thanks for the comment! I would like not to tamper with the encoding as this could be kind of dangerous IMHO - I hope I find a way to supply the charset like this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.schlichtherle/truezip/6.8.3/de/schlichtherle/nio/charset/IBM437Charset.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is an extended charset for Java. The name is right and PDF417 needs it by default. Android may not support it. What happens if you choose a different encoding? That is likely the best answer if you must encode this format on Android.

EDIT: This is mostly work-around-able. https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/105

Comment: I would like not to tamper with the encoding as this could be kind of dangerous IMHO - I hope I find a way to supply the charset like this: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.schlichtherle/truezip/6.8.3/de/schlichtherle/nio/charset/IBM437Charset.java

Comment: Actually I think this is fixable. It doesn't actually use the Charset for encoding, just the name. So this can be avoided

Comment: should I open a issue on github for this?

Comment: The Charset is used for the byte compaction mode. I think it would be better to have a fallback to ISO-8859-1 or similar which reflects the behaviour before version 3.0.0. (in the case that Cp437 isn't supported on the target platform)